# C# Конфиденциальные данные в TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, mvvm

Хочу написать свое приложение для шифрования конфиденциальных данных, этакий безопасный блокнот, с шифрованием проблем нет, там мне всё ясно. Вопрос следующий: как по правилам хранить конфиденциальные данные в TextBox, ведь они там будут находится в открытом виде относительно долго, от пары минут до пары часов, а насколько я могу судить из других статей - конфиденциальные текстовые данные ни в коем случае нельзя хранить в памяти в открытом виде.

Comment: Эээ, а как вы собираетесь показывать данные, которые вы не храните? Если мы говорим о защите данных, необходимо вначале сформулировать модель угроз: от чего конкретно вы собираетесь защищаться?

Comment: Данные будут хранится локально, в зашифрованном файле, человек запускает программу, выбирает файл, вводит ключ, и если ключ правильный - видит расшифрованные данные, в нашем случае текст. Он может его редактировать, всё как в блокноте. От чего хочу защитится, от возможности перехвата ключа или данных после закрытия или во время работы программы при условии, что у атакующего есть физический доступ к компьютеру.

Comment: Если у атакующего есть физический доступ к компьютеру, то вы уже проиграли. Он может просто вытащить жёсткий диск, и подменить вашу программу на свою. Ну или хотя бы подключить клавиатуру через аппаратный кейлоггер.

Comment: А вы свой рабочий каталог шифруете? Ну, так между прочим вопросец.  А работаете вы не под правами рута или админа на своем компьютере, а? И пароль у вашей учетной записи отвечает всем требованиям безопасности? Ну, это так лирика. А то пытаются писать программы с учетом супербезопасности, а сами при этом работают в системе с правами админа и под паролем 123.

Comment: И всё же, каким способом можно очистить память при завершении программы, дабы быть уверенным что все конфиденциальные данные затёрты??

Answer (score 0):

Для `UWP` есть специальный контрол `PasswordBox`. Почитайте про него, наверняка в `WPF` есть его прародитель.

Comment: Вы не могли бы прочитать про него и дополнить ответ, что бы он выглядел более убедительным.

Comment: можно попробовать использовать [защищённые строки](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx) которые    
`**пытаются** **избежать** хранения конфиденциальных строк в памяти процесса в виде обычного текста` но: (1)бесполезно, т.к. для отображения всё равно придётся преобразовать в обычный String, и (2)не удобно (добавление/изменение только по одному символу).